# FFmpeg HLS muxer .ts file name format

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

Is it possible to have `.ts` files named by date/time (any format) instead of sequence number when using the [HLS muxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html)?  If so, how can it be done?

```
ffmpeg -i - -hls-some-option-here test_stream.m3u8

test_stream_20141116174310.ts
test_stream_20141116174312.ts
test_stream_20141116174314.ts
test_stream_20141116174316.ts
```

Comment: i'm wanting to know the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [segment muxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment), which provides a more generic and flexible implementation of a segmenter, and can be used to perform HLS segmentation.

The segment muxer supports strftime expansion with `-strftime 1` (disabled by default). This allows segments to be named by time creation.

From `man ffmpeg-formats`:

> `strftime 1|0`
>
> Use the strftime function to define the name of the new segments to write. If this is selected, the output segment name must contain a strftime function template. Default value is 0.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec copy -map 0 -f ssegment -strftime 1 \
-segment_list test_stream.m3u8 -segment_time 10 test_stream_%Y%m%d%H%M%S.ts
```

`stream_segment` is a variant of the muxer used to write to streaming output formats, i.e. which do not require global headers, and is recommended for outputting e.g. to MPEG transport stream segments. `ssegment` is a shorter alias for `stream_segment`.

Comment: strftime is deprecated.

Comment: @Alam Is there a replacement for `strftime`?

Comment: @Brad I am not able to find one. Let me know if you find any replacement.

Comment: how do you use this with `out.m3u8` as last option?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for adding timestamp in ts file using ffmpeg. Only option left is making changes in ffmpeg code. You can modify libavformat/segment.c file. Modify `entry->filename` variable in  `segment_file()` function.